# Quickly redraw tooltip like MPC-HC's seekbar

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

If you hover your mouse over `Media Player Classic - Home Cinema`'s seekbar, a tooltip is visible with the duration time info. When you start to move your mouse horizontally across the seekbar, the tooltip smoothly follows the cursor along.

Using a regular tooltip control, the tooltip wont follow the cursor smoothly enough to see what time the cursor is over on the seekbar. I can't read C++ very well so I don't know how they are implementing that feature, but are they using a small custom window that looks like a tooltip or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very nice MPC-HC developer helped me out:

`How to Implement Tracking Tooltips`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx